# Alternative way of checking if an object is a match for any types in a given list

Tags: c#, list, class, inheritance, types

```
if (this.Page is ArticlePage|| this.Page is ArticleListPage)
{
   //Do something fantastic
}
```

The above code works, but given the fact there could be many different classes I'd want to compare `this.Page` to, I would like to store the classes in a list and then perform a `.Contains()` on the list.

How would I achieve this? Would I use `GetType()` somehow? Could I store a list of `Page` objects and then compare the types somehow?

*Note: You can assume all of the classes I'm comparing `this.Page` to extend `Page`.*

Comment: You should never write this type of code.  When you find yourself doing such a thing find a proper way to use polymorphism.  Polymorphic behavior will allow you to select the appropriate behavior without type selection.

Comment: What would have been a better approach in the first place? Thanks mate.

Comment: Polymorphism:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science)

Comment: Would you consider at least creating an empty interface (say, `IDoSomethingFantastic`), having the page classes also implement the interface, then your check would be simply `if (this.Page is IDoSomethingFantastic)`? Extra bonus if you can essentially define/move the "Fantastic" stuff into those pages/interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will do the job:

```
HashSet<Type> knownTypes = new HashSet<Type>()
{
    typeof(ArticlePage),
    typeof(ArticleListPage),
    // ... etc.
};

if (knownTypes.Contains(this.Page.GetType())
{
   //Do something fantastic
}
```

EDIT: As pointed by Chris, you may want to consider type inheritance to fully mimic the behavior of `is` operator. That's a bit slower but can be more useful for some purposes:

```
Type[] knownTypes = new Type[] 
{ 
    typeof(ArticlePage), 
    typeof(ArticleListPage),
    // ... etc.
};

var pageType = this.Page.GetType();
if (knownTypes.Any(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(pageType)))
{
    //Do something fantastic
}
```

Comment: Great, +1. Looks pretty much what I'm after. Why have you used HashSet as opposed to a list though (curiosity)?

Comment: @DeeMac HashSet is faster when it has more than 10 items.

Comment: Also note that this is _technically_ not the same behaviour. The original code using `is` checks also checks for subclasses and interface implementations. This code will check for the _exact matching type_. That means if you pass in a derived subclass of `ArticlePage` or `ArticleListPage`, or you registered interfaces, it will not pass. EDIT: It may work fine for your current usage, but just be aware of it in the future if you decide to use it otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Thanks for pointing this out. If one wants the full `is` equivalence then `IsAssignableFrom` method should be used for type checking. That's a bit slower but can be more useful in some situations.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to comment on your exact usage, but a (relatively) easy way to do this and add a bit more tidyness to your checks (*especially* if you perform the same checks in multiple places) is to define an interface, have the relevant pages implement that interface, then do the check against that.

The empty interface:

```
public interface IDoSomethingFantastic
{

}
```

So for example, your two page definitions might look like:

```
public partial class ArticlePage : System.Web.UI.Page, IDoSomethingFantastic
{

}

public partial class ArticleListPage : System.Web.UI.Page, IDoSomethingFantastic
{

}
```

Then your check is essentially:

```
if (this.Page is IDoSomethingFantastic)
{
    //Do something fantastic
}
```

This has the benefit of not having to centrally store a list of "fantastic" pages; instead you just define it on the page class declarations and it becomes easy to add/remove "fantastic" pages.

Additionally, you may be able to move your "fantastic" behaviour to the interface/page:

```
public interface IDoSomethingFantastic
{
    void SomethingFantastic();
}
```

Then in your checking code:

```
if (this.Page is IDoSomethingFantastic)
{
    ((IDoSomethingFantastic)this.Page).SomethingFantastic();
}
```

This way the implementation of something fantastic is handled elsewhere and not duplicated. Or you may move the checking and actions to a separate handling class altogether:

```
if (FantasticHandler.IsPageFantastic(this.Page))
    FantasticHandler.DoSomethingFantastic(this.Page);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you should double reconsider using such code (because it seems to forget about polymorphism), you can use Reflection to check it:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() 
{ 
    typeof(ArticlePage), 
    typeof(ArticleListPage) 
};
types.Any(type => type.IsAssignableFrom(@object.GetType()));
```

`IsAssignableFrom` will be true not only for specific class but also for all its subclasses, exacly like `is` operator.