# C# More elegant way to check if an exception is within a list of specified exceptions?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a need to check if an exception is within a list of specified exceptions and currently my code looks like:

```
catch (Exception ex) {
  if ( (ex is Exception1) || (ex is Exception2) || (ex is Exception3) || (ex is Exception4) || (ex is Exception5) ) { 
    //do something; 
  }
}
```

As you can see the syntax is not very elegant. Is there a better/cleaner way to write this type of expression in C#?

Edit - I was looking for some better build in syntax to treat Exceptions as types so maybe I can build a list of these exceptions and just use something like if a list object includes this ex. Anyway, I think I can bear with the current code for now.

Comment: Define "elegant"?  There's not a built-in syntax to do that.  Only other way I can think of is a list of types and a loop or Linq query, which is _less_ elegant in my opinion.

Comment: You should have a clean inheritance model of all these exceptions and then catch just the right parent of all exceptions of interest.

Comment: Check this question; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136035/catch-multiple-exceptions-at-once

Comment: Are we barking up the wrong tree here? I mean, why do you need to distinguish all these exceptions? Usually, if you really need, you just log the exception information and take safe measures to exit the code path. I hope that you are not driving your code flow using exceptions.

Comment: Related: how to check an object's type against a list of types: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20333634/945456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void test()
{
    try
    {
       // do something something
       return;
    }
    catch (Exception1) {}
    catch (Exception2) {}
    catch (Exception){
       return;
    }

    //do something; 
}
```

Is not very 'beautiful' but it works.. if any of Exception1 or Exception2 is encountered then `//do something` will execute. If another exception (represented by the general `Exception`) is hit then the method will return and it will not do anything (it will not execute `//do something`).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should not make this solution. It's better to catch each exception in a block, as follow:

```
catch (Exception1 ex) {
}
catch (Exception2 ex) {
}
```